# Prove that this set is a borel set

Tags: borel-sets

I have difficulties proving the following :

Let A be the set of all real x between [0 , 1], such that x has a decimal representation and each digit has infinite occurence. Now, what i do understand is, that a borel set is a set that can be constructed using countable union or intersection. But i dont really see a way to construct this set, since there are uncountably many of such x.
Any guesses?

Comment: There are uncountable many points in $(0,1)$ but it is an open set, so Borel.

Answer (score 2):

First note that the numbers with non-unique decimal representation are not in $A$, and neither of their two representations (one ending in $000\ldots$ and one in $999\ldots$ has infinitely many of any digit other than $0$ or $9$.
So we may restrict our attention to the representation that, in case of non-uniqueness, ends in $0$'s.  Let $D_n(x)$ be the $n$'th digit of $x$ in this representation. We have $A = A_0 \cap \ldots \cap A_9$, where $A_d$ is the set of numbers whose decimal representation has infinitely many $d$'s.
Now $x \in A_d$ iff for every positive integer $m$ there is integer $n > m$ such that the $n$'th digit of $x$ is $d$.  That says
$$ A_d = \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m+1}^\infty \{x\in (0,1): D_n(x) = d\}$$
And finally, write $\{x \in (0,1): D_n(x) = d\}$ as a finite union of intervals.

Comment: (+1) I was thinking of giving a brief hint, and also mention that one should not overlook that countably many reals have two expansions (countably, because each such corresponds to a rational number) and asking the OP to think about why this has no effect on Borel'ness, but now I don't even need to do this.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer, i finally understand :) !